# Why are numerical values stored as factors in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R interpreting variable in data frame as factor; it isn’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244147/r-interpreting-variable-in-data-frame-as-factor-it-isnt)

I am having an issue with some code I've written in R and I think my problems are stemming from a poor understanding of factors in R.

**What I am trying to do:** I have a column numbers and I want to create another column of bin descriptions (e.g. 1,2,3, etc which correspond to bin1, bin2, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
## import data to data frame
rawData = read.table("Data.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

## reduce socre into bins
rawData["s10_BIN"] = NA
for(i in 1:length(rawData[,"foo"]))
    {
        if(rawData[i,"s10"] > 0 && rawData[i,"s10"] <= .5)
        {
            rawData[i,"s10_BIN"] = 1
        }
        else if(rawData[i,"s10"] > .5 && rawData[i,"s10"] <= 1)
        {
            rawdata[i,"s10_BIN"] = 2
        }
        else if(rawData[i,"s10"] > 1 && rawData[i,"s10"] <= 1.5)
        {
            rawData[i,"s10_BIN"] = 3
        }
        else if(rawData[i,"s10"] > 1.5 && rawData[i,"s10"] <= 2)
        {
            rawData[i,"s10_BIN_BIN"] = 4
        }
        else
            rawData[i,"s10_BIN"] = 0

    }
```

I keep getting the error

```
1: In Ops.factor(rawData[i, "s10"], 0) : > not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(rawData[i, "s10"], 0.5) :
  <= not meaningful for factors
```

Can someone give me insight as to what I am missing? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here are the first 2 rows of the data:

```
 rawData[1:2,]
        ID PRODUCT  GROUP     MARKET   s10  CLAIMS   NUM_CLAIMS   s10_BIN
1        1    foo     A        C       NULL    -5          2         NA
2        2    foo     A        D      1.064     1          1         NA
```

I have a feeling the issue may be the NULL values...

Comment: `read.table()` apparently interprets your csv file as factors (or as strings, which are then turned into factors). This depends on what those columns in the original file contain. Could you look at and maybe include the first few lines of the file? In addition, you may want to use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table()` to force R to treat some columns as numerical.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244147/r-interpreting-variable-in-data-frame-as-factor-it-isnt/14244265#14244265) duplicate question.

Comment: Once you've solved this problem (which as others have pointed out will be tied to the formatting in your file, or unusual characters in some columns) you'll also want to look at the function `cut`. It will save you lots and lots of typing.

Comment: @Justin great link - that was extremely useful. Sorry for the duplicate - I tried searching but apparently not hard enough...

Comment: If the errant strings are NULL in your numeric columns, please read `?read.table` carefully and pay particular attention to the `na.strings` argument.